# R symbol background for custom symbols

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I have an R plot where I use the values as symbols. The points also have error bars:
[image]

The problem is, obviously, that the error bars (I use arrows for that) cross through the numbers and that just looks ugly and makes them hard to read.

This is my code, any ideas?

```
x = c(45.58333, 89.83333, 114.03333,138.65000,161.50000,185.15000,191.50000)
y_mean = c(3.350000,6.450000,7.200000,7.033333,8.400000,7.083333,6.750000)
y_sd = c(0.1802776,0.1732051,0.2500000,0.2020726,0.3500000,0.2020726,0.1000000)

values = data.frame(x, y_mean, y_sd)

plot(values$x, values$y_mean, type="n")

arrows(values$x, values$y_mean - values$y_sd, 
  values$x, values$y_mean + values$y_sd, 
  length=0.05, angle=90,
  code=3, col="red")

lines(values$x, values$y_mean, type="b",
  pch=" ",
  col="red", bg="white")

text(values$x, values$y_mean, label=round(values$y_mean), col="red")
```

EDIT:
I executed the exact code shown above as asked:
[image]

Comment: any reproducible data to play with?

Comment: Yes, sure, I added it :-).

Comment: `values$y_mean`, `values$y_sd`?

Comment: Sorry, my code is actually way more complex (pulling out of SQL db, aggregating multiple curves etc) so I just made this code here up not to annoy you with all the rest... Now it should work

Comment: I'd suggest you to run your provided data as well as your code and see if you get the same plot you posted. I suppose you won't.

Comment: I did it (look at the result above) and the problem still does persist :-(.

Comment: You edited your post after my comment! Your edition history is visible ;) Not it works.

Comment: Ah, you mean there were still bugs, that's true. As I said, I just made up the code above to demonstrate the problem, it's not my real code.

Comment: No I meant this line `plot(values$x, values$y_mean, type="n")` was not included in your initial provided code. Btw, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to white out the plot content where the text will be drawn, *before* drawing the text. This can be done with [`rect()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/rect.html). Although you risk whiting out the error bars entirely with this approach.

We can use [`strwidth()` and `strheight()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/strwidth.html) to get the appropriate sizes for the whiteout rectangles.

```
x <- c(45.58333, 89.83333, 114.03333,138.65000,161.50000,185.15000,191.50000);
y_mean <- c(3.350000,6.450000,7.200000,7.033333,8.400000,7.083333,6.750000);
y_sd <- c(0.1802776,0.1732051,0.2500000,0.2020726,0.3500000,0.2020726,0.1000000);
xlim <- range(x);
ylim <- c(min(y_mean-y_sd),max(y_mean+y_sd));
plot(NA,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,xlab='x',ylab='y');
arrows(x,y_mean-y_sd,x,y_mean+y_sd,length=0.05,angle=90,code=3,col='red');
lines(x,y_mean,type='b',pch=' ',col='red',bg='white');
ls <- as.character(round(y_mean));
ex <- 0.4; ## whiteout expansion factor
lsw <- strwidth(ls); w <- lsw/2*(1+ex);
lsh <- strheight(ls); h <- lsh/2*(1+ex);
rect(x-w,y_mean-h,x+w,y_mean+h,col='white',border=NA);
text(x,y_mean,ls,col='red');
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! :-D

Answer (score 3):

I would play with the horizontal justification and add small points to keep track of the original position

```
points(values$x, values$y_mean, pch=19, col="red", cex=0.5)
text(values$x, values$y_mean, label=round(values$y_mean), col="red", adj = -0.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just apply these changes:

```
plot(values$x, values$y_mean, type="n", 
xlim = c(min(values$x), max(values$x) + 20), 
ylim = c(min(values$y_mean)-1, max(values$y_mean)+1))

text(values$x, values$y_mean, label=round(values$y_mean), col="blue",  pos = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but another way to solve it :-).

Comment: well, minor changes gave rise to a solution. You stated your problem as follows: `The problem is, obviously, that the error bars (I use arrows for that) cross through the numbers and that just looks ugly and makes them hard to read.`. And now, it does not look ugly and it's easy to read. Mission accomplished :)